# ARC in Swift 2.2 deinit getting called - still having one reference

Tags: swift2, automatic-ref-counting

I am referring to ARC in swift 2.2 from developer.apple.com ( refer :- [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) )

I have the below code , the denit method is called, but I still have my reference 3 var not set to nil , Can anyone please explain why does the denit gets called ?.

in person.swift class

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("\(name) is being initialized")
    }
    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}
```

Inside my View Controller

```
   var reference1 : Person?
    var reference2 : Person?
    var reference3 : Person?

    reference1 = Person(name:"John Apple")

    reference2 = reference1
    reference3 = reference1

    reference1 = nil
    reference2 = nil
```

output :-

```
John Apple is being initialized
John Apple is being deinitialized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that as `reference3` is a local variable, as opposed to an instance variable, it's going out of scope when the method returns.

And BTW that person's name is John Appleseed, not John Apple :)

Comment: Hi trojanfoe......can you paste what is your version of code and I can test the same running in xcode.

Comment: @Max I don't understand what you mean.  You wanted to know why the object was released; there was no broken code as such.